# Boto3 Creating Account Assignment returns a in-progress and later fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

**env: python3 venv and using boto3 apis**

I have created a group and a permission set in identity store and want to assign the group to permission set. (through apis. got IDs and arns from creation response)

creating permission set:

```
def create_permission_set(self, instance_arn, name):

        client = boto3.client('sso-admin', aws_access_key_id=self.access_key,aws_secret_access_key=self.secret_key, region_name =self.region_name)

        response = client.create_permission_set(
            InstanceArn=instance_arn,
            Name=name
        )
```

Both the group and the permission set are present in the identity store.

But when I try to assign group to permission set using this code

```
    def bind_group_permission_set(self,permission_set_arn,group_id,instance_id,instance_arn):

        client = boto3.client('sso-admin', aws_access_key_id=self.access_key, 
                                aws_secret_access_key=self.secret_key, 
                                region_name =self.region_name)
        
        response = client.create_account_assignment(
            InstanceArn=instance_arn,
            PermissionSetArn=permission_set_arn,
            PrincipalId=group_id,
            PrincipalType='GROUP',
            TargetId='8xxxxxxxxxxxx3',
            TargetType='AWS_ACCOUNT'
        )
        return response
```

It returns "in progress" as the status and later fails when I get status from **SSOAdmin.Client. list_account_assignment_creation_status**

the result of assignment :

```
{'AccountAssignmentCreationStatus': 
{'PermissionSetArn': '', 'PrincipalId': '', 'PrincipalType': 'GROUP', 'RequestId': '', 'Status': 'IN_PROGRESS', 'TargetId': '', 'TargetType': 'AWS_ACCOUNT'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Thu, 11 Jan 2024 06:05:43 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '334', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': ''}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

How do I make sure it won't be going to a "in progress" state and goes straight to a "failure" or a "success"

As per the document I will be getting failure reason if failed, but this didn't fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, you're expected to...

> After a successful response, call `DescribeAccountAssignmentCreationStatus` to describe the status of an assignment creation request.

This is the only way to receive a `FailureReason` from the `AccountAssignmentCreationStatus`. Which, to be fair, is not made that obvious in the documentation.

The following simplified example tries to create the assignment and then uses [backoff](https://pypi.org/project/backoff/) to wait and check for the status for up to 30 seconds:

```py
import boto3
import backoff

sso_admin_client = boto3.client("sso-admin")

# wait for account assignment creation status, usually takes <5 seconds
@backoff.on_predicate( # retries until the function returns True
    backoff.constant,  # constant backoff
    interval=4,  # wait _ seconds between each try
    max_time=30)  # maximum wait time is _ seconds
def wait_for_account_assignment_creation_status(instance_arn, assignment_request_id):
    if sso_admin_client.describe_account_assignment_creation_status(InstanceArn=instance_arn, AccountAssignmentCreationRequestId=assignment_request_id)['AccountAssignmentCreationStatus']['Status'] == 'SUCCEEDED':
        return True
    return False


# create the association in the AWS SSO instance
def create_account_assignment(instance_arn, account_id, permission_set_arn, principal_type, principal_id):
    response = sso_admin_client.create_account_assignment(InstanceArn=instance_arn,
                                                            TargetId=account_id,
                                                            TargetType='AWS_ACCOUNT',
                                                            PermissionSetArn=permission_set_arn,
                                                            PrincipalType=principal_type,
                                                            PrincipalId=principal_id)
    # ToDo: check if the response failed right away

    # wait for the association to be created
    if not wait_for_account_assignment_creation_status(instance_arn,
                                                        response['AccountAssignmentCreationStatus']['RequestId']):
        failure_reason = sso_admin_client.describe_account_assignment_creation_status(InstanceArn=instance_arn, AccountAssignmentCreationRequestId=response['AccountAssignmentCreationStatus']['RequestId'])['AccountAssignmentCreationStatus']['FailureReason']
        raise ValueError(f"Timeout - reason {failure_reason}")

    # creation successful
```

In my case, the failure reason told me that the role I assigned was missing the permissions to create and assign roles in the target accounts:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "WriteAssociation",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "sso:CreateAccountAssignment",  // obvious
              "iam:ListRolePolicies",   // new
              "iam:GetSAMLProvider",   // new
              "iam:CreateRole",  // new
              "iam:AttachRolePolicy"  // new
          ],
          "Resource": "*"
      }
  ]
}
```